# AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'resource_filename'

Tags: python, linux, setuptools, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to install pgAdmin on Redhat and end up with below error,

```
Wed May 06 00:53:35.157756 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973] mod_wsgi (pid=6973): Failed to exec Python script file '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.wsgi'.
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.157820 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973] mod_wsgi (pid=6973): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.wsgi'.
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.157959 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158001 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.wsgi", line 36, in <module>
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158009 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]      from pgAdmin4 import app as application
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158018 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.py", line 109, in <module>
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158023 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]    app = create_app()
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158031 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973] File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 379, in create_app
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158036 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]    security.init_app(app, user_datastore)
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158043 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/flask_security/core.py", line 503, in init_app
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158048 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]      anonymous_user=anonymous_user)
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158055 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/flask_security/core.py", line 332, in _get_state
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158060 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]    i18n_domain=_get_i18n_domain(app),
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158067 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/flask_security/core.py", line 303, in _get_i18n_domain
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158073 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]  pkg_resources.resource_filename('flask_security', 'translations'),
[Wed May 06 00:53:35.158089 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6973]  AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'resource_filename'
```

when I run this file individually working fine, I wondered by it is throwing error while running app in web-browser.

Files have `_get_i18n_domain`:

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/flask_security/core.py
```

```
    def _get_i18n_domain(app):
        return Domain(
            pkg_resources.resource_filename(flask_security, translations),
            domain=cv('I18N_DOMAIN', app=app)
        )
```

`pkg_resources`& `setuptools` both are up to date but throwing error.

I found some similar posts as same as this issue, but none of them are giving solutions.

Any suggestion?

Comment: When you say, "running the app in a web-browser", how do you run the Python code in a web browser? Which posts had you found? The issue might be a version discrepency between `pgAdmin` and `setuptools`, consider downgrading `setuptools` or `pgadmin` and see if they play along. If that works, there's a version mix match issue with the packages. In 2018 that code worked: https://github.com/airshipit/drydock/blob/master/python/tests/unit/test_schema_validation.py

Comment: Kind of weird, because I can't find any source code containing `pkg_resources` or `resource_filename`. Looked through https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-source-code/ and `https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4`.

Comment: @Torxed , What I mean when try lunch pgAdmin from web-browser ‘localhost/phadmin4’.  and I have installed pgAdmin yum repo. and configured on httpd web server.

Comment: @Torxed, I'm not sure. Installed from the RPM package, security packages are installed at a location and didn't find in pgAdmin repo. `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/`